# QKeySequence::Quit shortcut not working in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I tried to add a shortcut for the quit action. However it doesn't show up in the menu.

Here's the code:

```
exitAct = new QAction(tr("&Exit"), this);
exitAct->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::Quit);
exitAct->setStatusTip(tr("Exit the application"));    
connect(exitAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(close()));
```

I tried the same thing for the print shortcut and it works so I don't see what I'm doing wrong here. Does anyone have an idea on how to ix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that is <kbd>Ctrl+Q</kbd> is assigned to QKeySequence::Quit for Mac OS X, but not for Windows. For Windows, no keyboard shortcut is assigned to QKeySequence::Quit.

Screenshot from Qt docs:

[image]

Comment: thanks, I thought Ctrl+Q was also working for windows.

Comment: No problem, I edited your question and tagged it with Windows.